# Is there a way to increase BTLE max chunk size for writing value i.e. CBCentral maximumUpdateValueLength?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to send 2k of data from my iPhone configured as a BTLE peripheral to my iPad. Right now the chunk size as dictated by CBCental::maximumUpdateValueLength is a mere 74 meaning it takes ~1s for transfering the payload. I'm wondering whether anyone knows a way of increasing this value (indirectly I presume)?  Maybe some configurable somewhere telling the iPhone its ok to use more power for BTLE?

More details:

- [Maximum data size when sending data via BTLE on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349945/maximum-data-size-when-sending-data-via-btle-on-ios)
- [Reading long characteristic values using CoreBluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280429/reading-long-characteristic-values-using-corebluetooth)

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: You should have more than 74 bytes according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977767/iosble-get-negotiate-mtu/42336001#42336001)

Comment: Hmmm. I'm using an iPod touch 5th gen. Maybe that's lower??